# jQuery UI - after download, jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, single-page-application, pickadate

I just download jquery ui (by npm) and I wanted to use datepicker. Right now on my page there is info with bug:

```
widget.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at widget.js:24
at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js (widget.js:26)
at newRequire (it-spa.4bb7a28f.js:47)
at localRequire (it-spa.4bb7a28f.js:53)
at Object.parcelRequire.src/it-spa.js.bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css (it-spa.js:4)
at newRequire (it-spa.4bb7a28f.js:47)
at it-spa.4bb7a28f.js:81
at it-spa.4bb7a28f.js:120
```

Please, help.

Comment: If you've included "jquery ui" then you also need to (separately) include "jquery" (first).  Ensure you have the correct versions, not just latest as each version of jquery ui needs a specific version of jquery.

Comment: as @freedomn-m said this probably has to do with how you imported the files. make sure you import jquery first then ui after.

Answer (score 0):

Try It ,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```